# Can we do supervised learning through HMM?

Tags: python, hidden-markov-models, supervised-learning, hmmlearn

I believe I understand HMM at its core. Through HMM we solve evaluation (prob of emitted seq), decoding (most probable hidden seq), and learning problem (learning transition and emission prob-matrix from observed set of emission seq).

My problem is associated with the learning problem. I have emission sequence but with that I also have associated features (meaning hidden state value, but the number of hidden states is not known) for each sequence. As in learning problem of HMM, we estimate hidden-sequence (size and prob-matrix) and for that we just need emission sequence (size of hidden sequence can be optimized if not known in advance).

I am using HMM [library](http://hmmlearn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html) for my computation. Of course, it does not have 
the option I want.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from hmmlearn import hmm

filenames =  [f for f in os.listdir(dir_path) if '.csv' in f.lower()]
d1 = pd.read_csv(dir_path + filenames[0]).as_matrix() # Shape = [m, 3] => first two column is featute and last is the emission-state 
d2 = pd.read_csv(dir_path + filenames[1]).as_matrix() # Shape = [m, 3]


##
remodel = hmm.GaussianHMM(n_components=4, covariance_type="full", n_iter=100)

remodel.fit(d1[:, 0:2])  # Problem would have been solved if there was supervised option to pass the states as well 

pred_1 = remodel.predict(d1[:, 0:2])
true_1 = d1[:, -1] # Last column is state of the feature in 1, 2 column.

pred_2 = remodel.predict(d2[:, 0:2])
true_2 = d2[:, -1]
```

Is there a way to do supervised learning in HMM, if yes then how? If not then can I still solve my problem using HMM? If it is possible then how?

Answer (score 6):

`hmmlearn` does not implement supervised learning ([hmmlearn#109](https://github.com/hmmlearn/hmmlearn/issues/109)).

The [seqlearn](https://github.com/larsmans/seqlearn) library implements supervised HMMs, but does not seem to implement GMMs.

The library [pomegranate](https://github.com/jmschrei/pomegranate) however seems to implement supervised Hidden Markov Models with Gaussian Mixture Models. Something like this:

```py
import pomegranate as pg

X = ...
y = ...
distribution = pg.MultivariateGaussianDistribution
model = pg.HiddenMarkovModel.from_samples(distribution, n_components=5, X=X, labels=y, algorithm='labeled')
```

Comment: Just realized that this is only a single Gaussian - not a mixture of Gaussian (GMM)